# Unable to install the application with same version

Tags: iphone, ipad, version, ipa

I have an ipa file of the application. It works fine when I install it for 1st time.
Then if I try to install the application again with same ipa file application crashes with device logs as below. (I didn't delete already installed application from device).

/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/X.app does not have an executable path. Please check the bundle's Info.plist file.

If I change version of the application it works fine.
I want to do it without changing the version.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you need to delete the app from the device if you're not going to change the version. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7266951/2030) for further explanation.